# default sorting for kendo grids if no defaultSortField is given

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and I pass back data in an array for my grid that looks something like this:

```
{
    "samples": [
        {
            "sampleId": "s1",
            "sampleName": "sample1"
        },
        {
            "sampleId": "s2",
            "sampleName": "sample2"
        },
        {
            "sampleId": "s3",
            "sampleName": "sample3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Because my sampleId is a string and not a number, I want to be able to just show the order that gets passed back from the server.  I don't define a `defaultSortField` or `defaultSortDir` and in Firefox, Safari, IE, my data shows up like it's supposed to.  In Chrome for some reason, it changes the order.  It changes the order consistently though.  Like if I have the structure shown above, but have 200 samples, I'll get sample sample103, then sample1, sample2, etc.  Some others might be messed up as well.  I'm trying to understand the default sorting for kendo grids if it's not defined and why it works differently on chrome.  I don't want to manually set the defaultSortDir to sampleId since it'll sort it as a string.  When I pass in

```
this.grid.serverSorting = true;
```

Then in chrome it does show up correctly.  However, for some reason, I'm not sure if it's because it's a grid that uses local data, when I click one of the headers to sort on a different column, my data just disappears.  Ideally, I'd just like to return the data properly on the first go in Chrome if that's possible.  Any thoughts?  thanks in advance.

Comment: In your datasource set the sort field.  `sort: { field: "sampleName", dir: "desc" }`

Comment: @RickS That's what I don't want to do by default, b/c then the output would be: "s1, s10, s100, s101, s102, ..." sorting it by that field as a string.  I just want the data to be sorted in the order the server sends it back, and then have the ability to sort the grid using the same local data.  If I turn server side sorting on, then I have to make a request to the server each time I believe.

Comment: Your sampleName field contains s1, s10, s100..? I thought those are your sampleIds?